# Dynamically creating a table using prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, prawn

I'm trying to write the code for a dynamically sized tabled in Ruby on Rails using Prawn gem. Essentially, this table checks if certain info is to be displayed, and if so, will change its rows/cells accordingly. There is also static rows/cells such as headers in this table which will be hardcoded. The dynamic data will be checked if it exists via a for each loop but I don't know where to code that foreach loop. My code with the **wrong** syntax:

```
    table_data = [[Prawn::Table::Cell::Text.new( pdf, [0,0], :content => "Title", :align            => :center, :inline_format => true, :size => 12)], 
                 object.objectProperties.each do |f|
                    [Prawn::Table::Cell::Text.new( pdf, [0,0], :content => f.getSpecificProperty, :align => :center, :inline_format => true, :size => 12)]
                    end
                ]
```

Obviously, ruby does not allow the foreach loop placed within the table_data because that is just syntactically wrong (I just wrote it there to give you an understanding of what I am trying to achieve).  My question is how can I work around this? Where should I check if those properties exist and how would I create and append the corresponding cells that depend upon the existence of the properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dynamic_data = []
object.objectProperties.each do |f|
    # populate dynamic_data array
end

table_data = [[Prawn::Table::Cell::Text.new( pdf, [0,0], 
               :content => "Title", :align => :center, 
               :inline_format => true, :size => 12)], dynamic_data]
```

Comment: works like a charm. I was very close to this but I was trying to build the table_data in the `each do` loop. Thank you!